# Is this a correct C++11 double-checked locking version with shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

This [article](http://preshing.com/20130930/double-checked-locking-is-fixed-in-cpp11/) by Jeff Preshing states that the double-checked locking pattern (DCLP) is fixed in C++11. The classical example used for this pattern is the singleton pattern but I happen to have a different use case and I am still lacking experience in handling "atomic<> weapons" - maybe someone over here can help me out.

Is the following piece of code a correct DCLP implementation as described by Jeff under ["Using C++11 Sequentially Consistent Atomics"](http://preshing.com/20130930/double-checked-locking-is-fixed-in-cpp11/#using-c11-sequentially-consistent-atomics)?

```
class Foo {
    std::shared_ptr<B> data;
    std::mutex mutex;

    void detach()
    {
      if (data.use_count() > 1)
      {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
        if (data.use_count() > 1)
        {
          data = std::make_shared<B>(*data);
        }
      }
    }

public:
  // public interface
};
```

Comment: If you're guarding `data` with a mutex, you don't need the `atomic_store`.

Comment: `use_count` is `const`, so by the general library rules, calling it concurrently does not cause a data race.

Comment: Note that your code is "best-effort" at best. The condition `data.use_count() > 1` is *not* fixed by the mutex! Existing copies can be destroyed concurrently.

Comment: @KerrekSB I heard about the `const` remark in Herbs [talk](http://herbsutter.com/2013/01/01/video-you-dont-know-const-and-mutable/). Would you really go so far as to assume, that this rule is generally implemented? Thanks for the hint on the needless `atomic_store` - I overlooked that.

Comment: Well, [res.on.data.races]/2 requires that const member functions don't modify objects. However, this is a bit unclear, since the making a copy of `data` clearly changes the use count. But the copy constructor takes a const value, so I would take that to mean that this does not constitute a modification that's relevant to data races. In practice I expect this to be data-race free, but it's not entirely clear from the standard as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ah, it's all fine. First off, the quoted paragraph basically says that the copy constructor does not "modify" the argument (because it's const). There's a clarification in [util.smartptr.shared]/4: "For purposes of determining the presence of a data race, member functions shall access and modify only the `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` objects themselves and not objects they refer to. Changes in `use_count()` do
not reflect modifications that can introduce data races."

Comment: @KerrekSB: Calling a `const` function concurrently with a non-`const` function (such as `operator=` as is done here) *may* cause a data race

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Sure, but that's not what's happening here. The modifying access is serialized through the mutex. The interesting aspect is that even though there may only ever be const views of `data`, the value of `data.use_count()` may still change.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a correct implementation of DCLP.

The thing is that your **outer check** `data.use_count() > 1` **accesses the object** (of type `B with reference count`), which can be deleted (unreferenced) in mutex-protected part. Any sort of memory fences cannot help there.

**Why** *data.use_count() accesses the object*:

Assume these operations have been executed:

```
shared_ptr<B> data1 = make_shared<B>(...);
shared_ptr<B> data = data1;
```

Then you have following layout (`weak_ptr` support is not shown here):

```
         data1             [allocated with B::new()]         data
                           --------------------------
 [pointer type] ref; -->   |atomic<int> m_use_count;|    <-- [pointer type] ref
                           |B obj;                  |
                           --------------------------
```

Each `shared_ptr` object is just a pointer, which points to allocated memory region. This memory region embeds object of type `B` plus atomic counter, reflecting number of `shared_ptr`'s, pointed to given object. When this counter becomes zero, memory region is freed(and `B` object is destroyed). Exactly this counter is returned by `shared_ptr::use_count()`.

**UPDATE**: Execution, which can lead to accessing memory which is already freed (initially, two shared_ptr's point to the same object, `.use_count()` is 2):

```
/* Thread 1 */                   /* Thread 2 */       /* Thread 3 */
Enter detach()                   Enter detach()
Found `data.use_count()` > 1     
Enter critical section                                   
Found `data.use_count()` > 1
                                 Dereference `data`,
                                 found old object.
Unreference old `data`,
`use_count` becomes 1 
                                                      Delete other shared_ptr,
                                                      old object is deleted
Assign new object to `data`
                                 Access old object
                                 (for check `use_count`)
                                 !! But object is freed !!
```

**Outer check should only take a pointer to object** for decide, whether to need aquire lock.

BTW, even your implementation would be correct, it has a little sence:

1. If `data` (and `detach`) can be accessed from several threads at the same time, *object's uniqueness* gives no advantages, since it can be accessed from the several threads. If you want to change object, all accesses to `data` should be protected by outer mutex, in that case `detach()` cannot be executed concurrently.
2. If `data` (and `detach`) can be accessed only by single thread at the same time, `detach` implementation doesn't need any locking at all.

Comment: All players, i.e. `data`, `mutex` and `detach()` are supposed to be members of a class. Thus, there is no way, that `data` gets deleted if detach() is being called. I will address this issue by modifying the question.

Comment: `there is no way, that data gets deleted if detach() is being called`. I mean, object *referenced by* `data` is unreferenced, because you assign new value to `data`. So, data.use_count() may access object, while shared_ptr doesn't point to it. This is misusing of shared_ptr, and may lead to accessing to freed memory, if other shared_ptr's, pointed to this object, are deleted at the same moment.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your scenario is only possible, if either thread 1 or thread 2 work on a reference to Foo - a reference owned by yet another thread. Your example assumes further that the owning thread of Foo kills it while the thread holding the reference is still working on it. If that is the case, then something is anyways substantially broken.

Comment: If your `data` reference is owned and accessed only by single thread, why you use locking? See point 2 at the very end of my answer.

Comment: I never said that the object should not be used by multiple threads but it should definitely not be deleted while one of the threads is accessing it - there is no protection against this use case. To be more clear, the use case I am aiming at with `Foo` is a copy-on-write implementation which takes advantage of the fact that `std::shared_ptr` is already reference counted in a thread safe way. The big pitfall is thread safe detaching on non-const member function calls on `Foo`. One problem without the mutex is e.g. creating multiple copies where one would have been sufficient.

Comment: Let's try to clarify the remaining issues. To rule out the _thread 3_ scenario let us assume that `Foo` is never being destroyed while it is used by any two threads. Let us also rule out your point 2. - as you already observed, the whole question would be moot in that scenario. Regarding your explanation, there is a misunderstanding of the code. **Outer check** never accesses `B`, `use_count()` is a member function of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: I do not get point 1 since either multiple threads just read `B` which is fine or at least one thread tries to write to `B` (i.e. use_count() > 1 in a multi-threaded scenario). In the latter case, `detach()` ensures that the thread writes to a uniquely owned `B` since after calling `detach()`, `use_count() == 1`.

Comment: I have updated answer with explanation `why .use_count() accesses the object` (of type `B with reference count`). If you want to prevent this object from deletion during `detach()` call, which possibly change `data` , you should have *another* `shared_ptr` pointed to it. But having another `shared_ptr` you force `data.use_count() > 1` be always true. Points at the end of my answer describe accesses to B only via `data`. Accesses via other `shared_ptr`s are not taken into account. Hope, these explanations will help.

Comment: Thanks for trying to clarify my questions. My current understanding is that you describe the general problem of dangling references. This problem is not solvable with "any sort of memory fences" as you stated in the answer and thus inherent to any use of a mutex within a member function - it is not DCLP specific. The answer does point out a valid and general programming issue. My question is really if ´use_count()´ can cause a race with the move assignment or copy construction of a ´shared_ptr´.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is right: the general problem of your code is dangling references. `data.use_count()` itself is not raced with `data1 = data;` copy construction. Concurrent access to `data.use_count()` and any method, modifiing `data` (e.g., `data = data1;` assignment) leads to dangling reference problem. It can be treated as race between accessing memory and freeing this memory.

Comment: I think we are on the right track. Can we agree that we ignore the use case where the `use_count()` drops to 0? If we don't even this code can break `{ lock_guard<mutex> lock{m_mutex}; other_code(); }`. The `lock_guard`'s destructor will call `std::mutex::unlock()` on `m_mutex` which is gone if the class owning `m_mutex` is deleted while some thread calls `other_code()`. My point is that the language offers no help for this scenario and that we should ignore it.

Comment: You misunderstand `use_count` protection: it protects object B plus counter itself from being freed. Object `Foo` is not deleted automatically when `use_count` drops to 0, so `mutex` is alive.

Comment: I understand `use_count()` quite well. I don't know any other way but to show a code example which demonstrates that your scenario may always crash: https://ideone.com/tbhYEp (please note that you have to test locally since ideone does not support multi-threading). If thread 3 kills `Foo`, it's game over. The `shared_ptr` is private and can only be destroyed via `Foo`'s destructor.

Comment: I think I finally catch what you want: each `Foo` object is accessed from single thread, and if `Foo foo1, foo2=foo1;`,  then only one of concurrent `foo1.detach()` and  `foo2.detach()` should create new B object; other should reuse current object. If so, your original DCLP becomes fully correct after you make `mutex` static.

Answer (score 1):

This constitutes a data race if two threads invoke `detach` on the same instance of `Foo` concurrently, because `std::shared_ptr<B>::use_count()` (a read-only operation) would run concurrently with the `std::shared_ptr<B>` move-assignment operator (a modifying operation), which is a data race and hence a cause of undefined behavior. If `Foo` instances are never accessed concurrently, on the other hand, there is no data race, but then the `std::mutex` would be useless in your example. The question is: how does `data`'s pointee become shared in the first place? Without this crucial bit of information, it is hard to tell if the code is safe even if a `Foo` is never used concurrently.

Comment: I initially used this code `std::atomic_store(&data, std::make_shared<B>(*other.data));` instead of the move assignment. If multiple threads create copies of `Foo` you are probably right and we need to implement construction, copying and assignment of `Foo` all in terms of `std::atomic_load/store`. Maybe someone else can confirm this before I edit the posting? @KerrekSB suggested that the 'std::atomic_store' is unnecessary but I am not sure anymore at least not when considering the whole class.

Answer (score 0):

According to your source, I think you still need to add thread fences before the first test and after the second test.

```
std::shared_ptr<B> data;
std::mutex mutex;

void detach()
{
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
  if (data.use_count() > 1)
  {
    auto lock = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>{mutex};
    if (data.use_count() > 1)
    {
      std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
      data = std::make_shared<B>(*data);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `std::shared_ptr::use_count()` is equivalent to an internal call to `std::atomic<long>::load()`. If that is true, then this [section](http://preshing.com/20130930/double-checked-locking-is-fixed-in-cpp11/#using-c11-sequentially-consistent-atomics) should apply and no fences are required. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @HaukeHeibel I don't know, I found no reference that either support or contradict that. Did you ?

Comment: @Nielk What happens if after the first `if`, another thread promotes a `weak_ptr` to `data` to a `shared_ptr`?